# Show that the series converges to 1

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to show the following:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{1}{r(r+1)} = 1. $$

I've found this series as part of a calculation to prove a formula for the Gamma function. I know it converges to 1 because of the result of this calculation, but otherwise I wouldn't even know how to find this value, so any help is appreciated with how to find out the series converges to 1 and/or how to prove it converges to 1 (in case these steps are done separately).

Comment: Can you split it in two sums, by partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: Try finding the partial sum formula, or see the telescoping behavior.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for pointing it out. I'd searched all over here, but it's difficult to find a specific series through the search form. I've typed it in different forms, to no avail. Any recommendations for searching this kind of thing in the future? I hate submitting duplicates.

Comment: How come you have studied math up to the gamma function, but you dont know about telescoping series ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Erm, judgmental much?

Comment: @ClementC. Not a bit of it, just think its incongruous, and I am curious why.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1

Comment: @ReneSchipperus It just happens that it's been a very long time since I've seen series convergence and I hadn't thought about telescoping series. I've always thought of this forum as a friendly environment to ask questions, even if they seem kind of dumb. I've included the context in which I've found it because I know this is encouraged here so that who's answering knows how much of a complete answer the person who's asking needs, and in fact the tips here were sufficient for me. Someone could interpret your comment as shaming and be discouraged to continue asking here or to provide context.

Comment: @RobbieVanDerzee I have seen that before, and I found it quite disgusting. This is the path to censorship, you need to be careful with that stuff cause it will burn you in ways you cant imagine.

Comment: @Wheepy Hey stop attacking me. I just wanted to know where you are coming from.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I'm not attacking you. I used the conditional ("someone could interpret your comment"). I hoped you'd interpret me literally as you seemed to hope I'd done with your comment. It really was a heads up for the future. I know this forum, so it wasn't a problem for me.

Comment: Sorry folks, didn't mean to make a fuss. All's well. =)

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I just meant to be nice.

Comment: @RobbieVanDerzee Yeah, well, I am not particularly pleased with this whole thing. Making a bit of banter is now not allowed. Not good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you see a factored polynomial in the denominator, think partial fractions. Consider the partial sums $$\sum_{r=1}^N\frac{1}{r(r+1)}=\sum_{r=1}^N\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}\right)$$
this sum is telescoping, and then take $N\to\infty$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hints:**
$$
\frac{1}{r(r+1)} = \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r+1}
$$
and "telescopic series".

Comment: (Very often, when dealing with these sort of series where you expect nice simplifications, partial fraction expansion is a good way to go.)

Comment: Although you were faster, I think I must choose the other answer for completeness (for the sake of future reference, in case this question isn't closed as a duplicate). I hope this is ok with you.

Comment: @Wheepy Sure, no worries.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a series expansion form of the digamma functions:
$$\psi^{(0)}(s+1)=-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{s}{n(n+s)}$$
You are then looking for

\begin{align}
\psi^{(0)}(2)+\gamma&=(1-\gamma)+\gamma \\
&=\boxed{1}
\end{align}

Comment: Do you really think that OP knows digamma function and Euler constant?

Comment: I was just posting another solution in case he did, or somebody else was interested.

Comment: I agree with @PrzemysławScherwentke - I do not know it yet, and it seems a little backwards to prove the convergence using such an advanced result (although it's a creative solution). In fact, I've found this series in Havil's book on the Gamma function, in the part he's introducing the digamma function. So I really needed the convergence before the expansion form of digamma.

Comment: Even tho OP probably would much prefer the telescoping sum. The digamma function usage might be of some help to future readers. This would also help tie in different aspects of math imo.

Comment: @The Integrator Yes, this is one of the reason why I posted this answer.

Comment: @TheIntegrator agreed.